# Open save link as dialog on click

Tags: javascript, html, browser

On click I want to open the dialog box ( which manually you have to right click and choose save link as)

How is it Possible using onclick attribute? It's important to open this dialog as the file will not get downloaded if it's a text file.

href attribute will hold blob data.

```html
<a target="_blank" href="#"> DOWNLOAD FILE</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `download` attribute to your anchor tag and the link of the file to be downloaded in the `href` attribute.

Somthing like this:

`<a href="http://www.example.com/file.jpg" download>Download</a>`

Comment: NICE ! I didn't know that attribute ; with HTML5, we can also add a value for `download` attribute, to suggest the filename to save the file to.

Comment: Happy to help! ;-)